# Start the first day of the week as Sunday in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want my first day of the week to be as Sunday but my issue with my code is that it starts always as Monday.

```
SELECT 
    UID,
    DATEADD(DD,CONVERT(INT, (DATEDIFF(DD, '1/1/1900', t.DT)/7)) * 7,'1/1/1900') [WeekBeginDate], 
    SUM(HOURS) AS TOTAL_HOURS 
FROM 
    myTable t 
WHERE 
    DT >= DATEADD(WEEK, -6, GetDate()) 
GROUP BY 
    UID, CONVERT(INT, DATEDIFF(DD, '1/1/1900', t.DT)/7)
```

Comment: Try this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set monday as first day of week in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031802/how-to-set-monday-as-first-day-of-week-in-sql-server)

Comment: it is not a duplicate, i have tried to solve it but having some issues with my solution.  thanks

Comment: What did you try and what issues did you have?   The knowledge contained in the answer to the duplicate should be sufficient to solve your problem.

Comment: I fail to see how this would even get close to being a duplicate of the linked question. The linked question is regarding set datefirst which has nothing to do with the logic calculating sunday as the first date(Calculating being the key word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT
  UID,  
  DATEADD(d, -1, DATEDIFF(d, -1, t.DT)/7 * 7) [WeekBeginDate] ,
  SUM(HOURS) AS TOTAL_HOURS 
FROM myTable t 
WHERE DT >= DATEADD(WEEK, -6, GetDate()) 
GROUP BY UID, DATEDIFF(d, -1, t.DT)/7
```