# Get Work week or Number of Weeks T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get the exact week number if my date range is from Friday to Thursday nextweek?
I used this code

```
datepart(wk,t.date) as workweek
```

but the week number is different, maybe because the format that I want to get is from Friday to Thursday nextweek. I hope somebody can answer. TIA!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set monday as first day of week in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031802/how-to-set-monday-as-first-day-of-week-in-sql-server)

Comment: Hi tim, maybe your answer is correct, Can you show me again your answer> Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SET DATEFIRST 5; -- Set Friday as first day of the week
Select datepart(wk,t.date) -1 as workweek
From yourTable as t
```

Comment: Hi why did you use -1?

Comment: @JackyMontevirgen I don't think you need the -1 there.

Comment: Actually, I saw the word "next week" in the requirements. Depending on the contents of t.Date, it will return the equivalent week number of that date which I assumed is one week ahead relative to the current week.

Comment: you may be all correct, -1 is not required, but that depends on what is t.Date.

Comment: @AhmedSaeed I try to put +1 and I got what I want. Thanks!

Comment: @AhmedSaeed if **DATEFIRST** gets the started day, how can I get the ended day?

Comment: DATEFIRST actually sets the starting day of the week Example "Friday" which implies that the ending day of the week is Thursday.