# Datepart and @@datefirst differences

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

It is my understanding that DateFirst is the first day of the week, or the day the week starts on. However, when I run these queries, my results do not match what I thought I understood

```
select @@datefirst,DATENAME(WEEKDAY,@@datefirst)
SELECT DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'20190113'),DATENAME(WEEKDAY,'20190113')
SELECT DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'20190114'),DATENAME(WEEKDAY,'20190114')
SELECT DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'20190115'),DATENAME(WEEKDAY,'20190115')
SELECT DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'20190116'),DATENAME(WEEKDAY,'20190116')
SELECT DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'20190117'),DATENAME(WEEKDAY,'20190117')
SELECT DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'20190118'),DATENAME(WEEKDAY,'20190118')
SELECT DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'20190119'),DATENAME(WEEKDAY,'20190119');
```

and I get

```
7 Monday (this is the @@datefirst line)
1 Sunday
2 Monday
3 Tuesday
4 Wednesday
5 Thursday
6 Friday
7 Saturday
```

How does @@datefirst give me 7 and the day give me Monday, whereas 7 is Saturday? Is this a config issue or a misunderstanding on my part?

Comment: I think this can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/q/20031802/9940803

Comment: `DATENAME` expects a date as its parameter, so passing it `7` is actually passing it `7 Jan 1900` which I assume is a `Monday`

Comment: @DaleBurrell is referring to this part of your code if you aren't following `DATENAME(WEEKDAY,@@datefirst)`. You should add that as an ander Dale :)

Comment: Its also worth noting that the value returned by `DATEPART` and `DATENAME` for `WEEKDAY` are relative to the value returned from `@@DATEFIRST`, which is absolute i.e. when `@@DATEFIRST` is `7` (always Sunday) `DATEPART` returns `7` which is Saturday (which had me confused). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @DaleBurrell in the following documentation they mentioned that if the input is not relative to the datepart specified it will return a default value. Check my answer for more info

Comment: Thanks @Hadi but my point is in addition to your answer and clarifies what happens when you use a valid date - as in this case the value of `DATEPART` is relative to `@@DATEFIRST` - see my link. Feel free to add this to your answer.

Comment: Aside: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the following [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> This function returns a character string representing the specified datepart of the specified date.
>
> **Syntax:** DATENAME ( datepart , date )

---

## Update 1

In the same article, in the Section: **Default Returned for a datepart That Is Not in the date Argument**

> If the data type of the date argument does not have the specified datepart, DATENAME will return the default for that datepart only if the date argument has a literal .
>
> For example, the default year-month-day for any date data type is 1900-01-01. This statement has date part arguments for datepart, a time argument for date, and DATENAME returns 1900, January, 1, 1, Monday

So when you enter the number `7` the input is considered as `1900-01-01 07:00:00` which return `Monday`

If you go to SQL Server and Run the following command

```
select DATENAME(WEEKDAY,'1900-01-01 07:00:00')
```

It returns

```
Monday
```

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of the `@@DATEFIRST` is correct.

The `@@DATEFIRST` is a function that returns the first day of the week and its default value depends on the system environment.

If you change for instance, the Language, the `@@DATEFIRST` default value will be changed according to that language settings. 
Although, `@@DATEFIRST` can be set manually without the need to change the language settings.

So, in your example results, Day number 7 (which is Sunday) is defined in your system as the first day of the week, however, when you use it in a date function (such as DATENAME() ), it'll give you an incorrect results, because `@@DATEFIRST` will return an integer (from 1 to 7) while the date functions takes a DATE or DATETIME inputs and not integers. Those, your method of using `@@DATEFIRST` is not efficient. `@@DATEFIRST` has multiple uses, one of these uses is to get the correct weekday.

Let's take a simple example. My current `@@DATEFIRST` settings is set to 7, and I want to make a scalar function that always gives me the date of the upcoming Sunday. So, I can use this :

```
SELECT DATEADD(DW, @@datefirst - DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) + 1 , GETDATE())
```

This will always gives me the next Sunday from today. Let's say, one of my clients is in another country has different start of week (let's say Monday = 1). I don't have to change anything in the code above, I only need to execute the following :

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
```

Now, this will give my client the first Monday from the current date, without the need to do further customization on my actual query.

This is just a simple example that gives you an idea on the usage of `@@DATEFIRST`

You can check these references to know more about it.

[@@DATEFIRST (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

[SET DATEFIRST (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)