# Datepart week start Monday used in a view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use the DATEPART function in my SELECT query that constructs a view.
The aim of the DATEPART is to return the weeknumber of a date passed to it. I require the start of the week to be a Monday and the default, which in my case is a Sunday.
I am not able to use `Set DATEFIRST 1` since I want to use the Datepart in a view.

eg. Lets use the date '2021-01-31' as [Date]

```
DATEPART(WEEK,DATE) --returns week 6 with @@DATEFIRST = 7
DATEPART(WEEK,DATE) --returns week 5 with @@DATEFIRST = 1
```

All suggestions would highly be appreciated.

Comment: May be this will help. :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031802/how-to-set-monday-as-first-day-of-week-in-sql-server

Comment: What about using `DATEPART(iso_week,...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can offer such a solution:

```
declare
    @DATE date='2021-01-31'

select DATEPART(WEEK,@DATE) --returns week 6 with @@DATEFIRST = 7
,DATEPART(WEEK,case when datepart(dw, @DATE)=1 then dateadd(dd, -1, @DATE) else @DATE end) --returns week 5 with @@DATEFIRST = 1
```