# Get only weekend data records from a database?

Tags: sql, database, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I am trying to get records for transactions that took place over the weekend (month over month analysis) and I am trying to write a SQL query to get the weekend records. I have a column which has the Date in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: You state what format is used. But DATETIME datatypes don't have a format, they're a binary datatype. Does that imply you're strong the dates as strings??

Comment: This is my first stackoverflow question but will keep these in mind, the answers I got worked with my query :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect you to have Saturday and Sunday rows using

```
WHERE DAYNUMBER_OF_WEEK (columnname) in (6, 7)
```

Or, perhaps

```
WHERE DAYNUMBER_OF_WEEK (columnname) in (1, 7)
```

Comment: I think this can change based off DB settings, so would have to test to see which one your DB is using for if it is 6,7  or 1,7 like above, so have to figure out what one your DB is using.  You can also force it what one to use see here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031802/how-to-set-monday-as-first-day-of-week-in-sql-server#:~:text=4%20Answers&text=SET%20DATEFIRST%201%3B%20this%20sets,week%20for%20the%20current%20connection.&text=You%20can%20use%20DATEPART(dw,value%207%20which%20is%20Sunday).

Answer (score 0):

If it's Teradata, you can use `sys_calendar.calendar` for this (and lots more).

```
select
...
from
<your table>
join sys_calendar.calendar
on <your table>.<date_column> = calendar.calendar_date
and day_of week in (7,1)
```

There is also the  `td_day_of_week(<date>)` function.